# Saving academic year to MySQL database based on now() timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a university help desk office where the employees use a php form to register the queries they have answered in a MySQL database.

Basically the form creates some values that are stored as variables in php and then saved in the database, like so:

```
$employeename = $_POST['employeename'];
$medium = $_POST['medium'];
$timespent = $_POST['timespent'];

$query = "INSERT INTO queries VALUES ('',now(),'$employeename','$medium','$timespent')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

This gives me the following table structure:

```
id | timestamp            | employeename | medium | timespent
 1 | 2015-11-30 10:52:57  | Jennifer     | e-mail | 5
 2 | 2015-11-30 10:55:02  | Jason        | phone  | 2
```

I'd like to add a column in my MySQL database that stores the academic year where each query is saved as I will be using this grouping quite often when counting how many queries was saved.

Our academic years are written 2013/2014, 2014/2015, 2015/2016, etc. Each academic year covers the period from 1 September to 31 August, meaning that e.g. all queries with timestamps from and including 2015-09-01 00:00:00 to but not including 2016-09-01 00:00:00 should save "2015/2016" in my academic year column in the database.

I am looking for the PHP code I would need to interpret "now()" from my MySQL query into the correct academic year and saving it to my database, preferably in a way where I won't have to add previous/coming academic years to my code (i.e. if a user saves a query in 1 September 2020 the script would automatically know to save the academic year as 2020/2021).

Any help would be much appreciated. I am sorry for not including any sample code. The reason is that I have no idea about how I would go about doing this and thus am unsure what to read up on.

Comment: It would be easier to use PHP's datetime class, instead of basing it on `NOW()`

Comment: Wouldn't I just need to create a variable and do another insert query after having interpreted the timestamp: $timestampfromdb = mysqli_insert_timestamp($con);

Comment: no need to add a column, you can derive this field in sql with year(timestamp) when selecting

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing that, but I am afraid that it will slow down the queries when I have 100,000+ queries answered in my db. I also assume that the php code to convert the timestamps to academic years would be pretty similar?

Comment: Weird requirements... Since you use PHP to generate SQL, it's plain impossible to process NOW()'s output with PHP. What prevents you from doing everything in a single language, either PHP or SQL? *(Side note: seeing code so wide open to SQL injection in 2015 makes my eyes bleed.)*

Comment: **Just store `NOW()` on the database in a TimeStamp column**. The time to add specific selection criteria is when you are writing the queries that select the data you want to process. This way you are never limited to what you can select in a query. For example if you want to know what happened in only the first term of Academic year 2014/2015, your way would not allow this

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I'll try going down this road instead. As I understand the answers I have received a good solution is to incorporate the "concat" example in my query in order to get the different academic year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula using MySQL:

```
 CONCAT(
    @a:=IF(MONTH(NOW())<9,YEAR(NOW())-1,YEAR(NOW())),
    "/",
    @a+1) year
```

This estimates the first year of the current academic year based on the month, and then concatenate the second year using a variable.

Comment: This query is great! Adding DISTINCT gives me values I can now use to populate a drop down.

Comment: This query works fine as a query in phpmyadmin but doesn't work on my php script: `$academicyear = "SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(@a:=IF(MONTH(timestamp)<9,YEAR(timestamp)-1,YEAR(timestamp)),"/",@a+1)) AS theacademicyear FROM queries";` I get a division by zero warning. Any idea what's wrong? EDIT: Found out, just had to replace double " with single '.

Comment: you have to replace the double quote near the slash to simple quotes

Answer (score 0):

Or add easy a new Field witch do this for you. If you use the PERSITENT Type you can also set an INDEX on it.

```
ALTER TABLE queries
ADD COLUMN `ayear` VARCHAR(10) AS (
  IF( `timestamp`  >= DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp` , '%Y-09-01 00:00:00') ,
    CONCAT( YEAR( `timestamp` ),'/',YEAR( `timestamp` )+1) ,
    CONCAT( YEAR( `timestamp` )-1,'/',YEAR( `timestamp` ))
  )
)  PERSISTENT;
```

**Here the Result and the CREATE TABLE:**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from queries;
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| id | timestamp           | ayear     |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00 | 2015/2016 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `queries` (`id`, `timestamp`) VALUES (2, '2015-08-01 00:00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `queries` (`id`, `timestamp`) VALUES (3, '2015-08-31 12:00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `queries` (`id`, `timestamp`) VALUES (4, '2015-09-15 15:00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from queries;
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| id | timestamp           | ayear     |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | 2015-12-01 00:00:00 | 2015/2016 |
|  2 | 2015-08-01 00:00:00 | 2014/2015 |
|  3 | 2015-08-31 12:00:00 | 2014/2015 |
|  4 | 2015-09-15 15:00:00 | 2015/2016 |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>

CREATE TABLE `queries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ayear` varchar(10) AS (
  IF( timestamp  >= DATE_FORMAT(timestamp , '%Y-09-01 00:00:00') ,
    CONCAT( YEAR( timestamp ),'/',YEAR( timestamp )+1) ,
    CONCAT( YEAR( timestamp )-1,'/',YEAR( timestamp ))
  )) PERSISTENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Am I right in understanding that this would have my database doing the interpreting of the date outside of php? Sounds like a very good solution. But when I try to just run your query in phpMyAdmin I get a syntax error.

Comment: sorry, if have tested. in my system its ok. you can only put the fieldname timestamp in backticks like `timestamp` . timestamp is a reserved

Comment: if have change it in my answer

Answer (score -1):

Carbon has functionality to give time stamps that are days, months, years before now. 
Say you have this academic year as:

```
$thisyear->carbon:now();
```

and the previous year

```
$preyear->carbon:now()->subYears(1);
```

Then pass both of these to strings and paste to Mysql as a range.

Comment: Did he say he was using Carbon?? That does nothing you cannot code in raw PHP anyway.

Comment: No carbon was a suggestion.

Comment: Its a bit __HAMMER to crack a nut__ as far as suggestions go